# Beamer: \againframe without creating a new page (i.e. simulate overlays)

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

**TL:DR: Is there a solution to fake overlay with mutiple frames?**

As explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597278/beamer-usebackgroundtemplate-only-problem-duplicated-frame-and-index-shift?noredirect=1#comment1497449_597278) I would like to add multiple backgrounds to a same set of overlays. [This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210867/change-beamer-frame-background-between-slides-in-same-itemize) gives a few solutions, but none of them is perfect: the first solution adds some margin, so one need to arbitrary increase the background until no margin is visible which may zoom a bit the background image, and the second solution seems better, but it adds new pages. Basically, this second solution adds some frames by adding new pages via:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{...}
\againframe<2>{myframelabel}
```

but unfortunately this adds new pages instead of overlays:

[image]

I managed to solve the page numbering problem by using some `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`, but unfortunately the miniframes (the dots in the top left part) are still bad...

Is there a solution to fake overlay with mutiple frames?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{use=structure,bg=darkred!80!black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  % \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  % \end{beamercolorbox}
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, left]{title in head/foot}%
      \hspace*{4ex}
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{%
        %\insertshortinstitute
      }{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.8\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, right]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{4ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test}

{
  \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \begin{frame}<1>[label=myframelabel]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<+-> a
      \item<+-> b
      \item<+-> c
      \item<+-> d
      \item<+-> e
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
  \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}\againframe<2>{myframelabel}
  \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}\againframe<3>{myframelabel}
  \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}\againframe<4->{myframelabel}
}

\begin{frame}
  Hello, I'm a new empty frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --

I finally found a problem to my original problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597278/beamer-usebackgroundtemplate-only-problem-duplicated-frame-and-index-shift/597339#597339), so I don't need anymore to solve that one, but of course I'm still curious to ear about answers.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234269/hide-some-slides-from-the-miniframes-navigation-in-beamer could help?

Comment: @Marijn it's a first start indeed thanks: it removes the dots, but does not highlight the dot of the current frame. Note also that I found a solution to my initial (different) problem (see edit), so I don't absolutely need the solution, but I'm quite curious to know if there is a solution.