# Beamer transition in combination with eso-pic

Tags: beamer, includegraphics, eso-pic

In a beamer presentation with transitions/overlays I would like to include slide-filling images in the background that transition at the same time. My attempt is to use eso-pic for this, but there is a mismatch occurring: the first slide shows the second image, the second slide shows the third image, etc. Here's an MWE showing the mismatch.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundtemplate{}
\begin{frame}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \includegraphics<1>[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
        \includegraphics<2>[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}%
        \includegraphics<3>[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-c}%
    }
}
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item<2-> B
    \item<3-> C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mismatch]

Is there an easy way to fix this mismatch? Perhaps eso-pic is not the appropriate package, but I would like the background images to not affect (the positioning of) the slide contents.

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210882/1952

Comment: Thank you! Indeed this appears to be a duplicate.