# Logo behind section labels in sidebar

Tags: beamer, templates

I have found a few questions talking about:

- placing images behind text in beamer, e.g. [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/beamer-how-to-place-images-behind-text-z-order) [(2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156903/how-to-include-image-in-background)
- adding logos to a beamer presentation, e.g. [(3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54577/how-do-i-customize-beamer-template)
- customizing a sidebar in beamer, e.g. [(4)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/customizing-the-sidebar-in-beamer)

But I haven't quite figured out how to get a template with an image behind the section headings in a sidebar.

So what I want is the following:

1. That the `\section` and `\subsection` labels show up as clickable links in a sidebar
2. That a logo appears in the sidebar.
3. That the logo does not move around when `\section` and `\subsection` are added.
4. That the image is placed behind the text.

How can this be achieved?

To illustrate what I want, I created a quick mockup, see below.

[image: The type of slides I am looking for]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! +1 for the lovely duck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sidebar canvas <which ever side>` template to place the logo behind the text of the sidebar:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[left]{Goettingen}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{%
\color{gray!20!white}%
\rule{\beamer@sidebarwidth}{\paperheight}

\vspace*{-.6\paperheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.4}
\begin{pgftransparencygroup}
    \penguin
\end{pgftransparencygroup}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{sec 1}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}

\section{sec 2}
\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]